# Swift 3: How do I pinch to scale and rotate UIImageView?

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am really struggling to find tutorials online as well as already answered questions (I have tried them and they don't seem to work). I have a UIImageView that I have in the centre of my view. I am currently able to tap and drag this wherever I want on screen. I want to be able to pinch to scale and rotate this view. How do I achieve this? I have tried the code for rotation below but it doesn't seem to work? Any help will be a massive help and marked as answer. Thank you guys.

```
    import UIKit

class DraggableImage: UIImageView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.backgroundColor = .blue

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.backgroundColor = .green

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: superview)
            center = CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y)
        }
    }

}

class CVController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateAction(sender:)))
        firstImageView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)

        setupViews()
    }

    func rotateAction(sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        let rotatePoint = sender.location(in: view)
        let firstImageView = view.hitTest(rotatePoint, with: nil)
        firstImageView?.transform = (firstImageView?.transform.rotated(by: sender.rotation))!
        sender.rotation = 0
    }

    let firstImageView: DraggableImage = {
        let iv = DraggableImage()
        iv.backgroundColor = .red
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return iv
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(firstImageView)

        let firstImageWidth: CGFloat = 50
        let firstImageHeight: CGFloat = 50

        firstImageView.frame = CGRect(x: (view.frame.width / 2) - firstImageWidth / 2, y: (view.frame.height / 2) - firstImageWidth / 2, width: firstImageWidth, height: firstImageHeight)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your rotation code appears to be correct. Have you tried setting up a break point in the debugger to see if the rotation gesture is recognized and if your rotation code is executed?

Comment: Not related to your issue but you could just pass the position `center = position`

Comment: btw you can just add the gesture recognizer to the main View and in your gesture selector method add `firstImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: gesture.rotation)
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a some problems in your code. First you need to add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your view controller and make it your gesture recognizer delegate. You need also to implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneously` method and return `true`. Second when applying the scale you need to save the transform when the pinch begins and apply the scale in top of it:

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = .green
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let position = touches.first?.location(in: superview){
            center = position
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    var identity = CGAffineTransform.identity
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupViews()
        
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scale))
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotate))
        
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        rotationGesture.delegate = self

        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    }
    let firstImageView: DraggableImageView = {
        let iv = DraggableImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .red
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return iv
    }()
    
    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(firstImageView)
        let firstImageWidth: CGFloat = 50
        let firstImageHeight: CGFloat = 50
        firstImageView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - firstImageWidth / 2, y: view.frame.midY - firstImageWidth / 2, width: firstImageWidth, height: firstImageHeight)
    }
    @objc func scale(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            identity = firstImageView.transform
        case .changed,.ended:
            firstImageView.transform = identity.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale)
        case .cancelled:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    @objc func rotate(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        firstImageView.transform = firstImageView.transform.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```